# Symfony 3.2 Form events : Can't retrieve data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.2

I didn't find any subject related to my question and my case is very particular that's why i am calling for help.

I have 4 involved entities : PurchaseOrder, SapPO, project and Product. As shown below there is a one to many association between PurchaseOrder and SapPo, and a one to many bidirectional association between SapPo and Project and a many to many association between purchaseOrder and product.

PurchaseOder.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SapPo",cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="po_sappo",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="po_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sappo_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true,onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 */
private $sapPo;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="purchaseOrders")
 */
private $products;
```

SapPo.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="sapPos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_sap", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $project ;
```

Project.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SapPo", mappedBy="project")
 */
private $sapPos ;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="projet")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_project")
 */
private $products;
```

And finally Product.php :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PurchaseOrder", inversedBy="products", 
  cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="purchaseOrders_products")
 */
private $purchaseOrders;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="products")
 */
private $projet;
```

What i want to do is to populate the form with products that represent the intersection between the chosen projects data.
For example we have to chosen project *"Project 1"* that has two products *"product 1"* and ***"product 2"*** and an other project *"project 2"* that has two products ***"product 2"*** and *"product 3"*.

In this example ***"product 2"*** is the intersection and the form need to be populated with it.

Using the code shown below and using the FormEvents i have succeeded to populate the form with the necessary data using the necessary AJAX calls and afterward an ArrayCollection Filter. The problem is that once i submit the form i don't get the products chosen but i get an empty ArrayCollection.

PurchaseOrderType.php :

```
        /**
     * Product modifier used to modify products after the SAP PO choice validation
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param $sapPos
     */

    $productModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $names){


        $form->add('products', EntityType::class,array(
            'class' => 'FollowupBundle:Product',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($names) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('u') ;
                $qb->where("u.name IN (:projects)")
                    ->setParameter('projects',$names) ;
                return $qb ;
            },
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => 'Selectionner le produit'
        ));
    };



    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            $sapPos = $data->getSapPo();



            $form->add('products',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'FollowupBundle:Product',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'choices' => [],
                'placeholder' => 'selectionner les produits',
                'choice_label' => 'name'


            )) ;

        }) ;



    $builder->get('sapPo')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($productModifier){
            $sapPos = $event->getForm()->getData() ;
            $namesList = $this->getNamesFromSapPo($sapPos) ;

            $productModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $namesList);
        },900
    ) ;
```

**EDIT**

This are the function used to filter and extract products names to be used in the query builder.

```
 /**
 * @param Product $product
 * @param ArrayCollection $sapPos
 * @return bool
 */
public function filterProducts(Product $product, $sapPos){
    $isCommon = true ;
    foreach ($sapPos as $sapPo){
        if (!$sapPo->getProject()->getProducts()->contains($product)){
            $isCommon = false;
        }else {
        }
    }
    return $isCommon;
}



public function getNamesFromSapPo($sapPos){
    $primilnaryProducts  = new ArrayCollection() ;
    $lastProducts = new ArrayCollection() ;
    $namesList = [] ;
    foreach ($sapPos as $sapPo){
        foreach ($sapPo->getProject()->getProducts() as $product){
            $primilnaryProducts->add($product) ;
        }
    }
    // filter products

    $lastProducts = $primilnaryProducts->filter(
        function ($entry) use ($sapPos){
            return $this->filterProducts($entry,$sapPos) ;
        }
    ) ;

    //get Names

    foreach ($lastProducts as $product){
        $namesList[] = $product->getName() ;
    }


    return $namesList ;



}
```

Any hint or technical advice is welcomed ! thanks.

Comment: As I see from `https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choices`
(and as I remember): your `'choices' => []` will override any data in field

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is that i forgot to use the form modifier in the POST_SUBMIT function.

Comment: Great. You found solution. BTW, more debugging while working with form events - is the best way to find all problems, of course if you are not writing them often.

Comment: I generally use PSR/Logger but sadly i can't log objects as in Java.

Comment: You could try to serialize your object before logging it. And, imo, logging is not the best way of debugging - try to play with xdebug, it is much more better.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to use the form modifier in the POST_SUBMIT function and i had to remove the 'choices' => [] from the form builder that overrides the data sent to the server.